# Angular 2 model in html (using http post)

Tags: http, model, typescript, angular

I'm currently learning Angular 2 and I have a problem with posting the model into my back-end.

This is how function looks:

```
  addDepartment(department: Department){
      var headers = new Headers();
        headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "http://localhost:65402";
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

     return  this.http.post('http://localhost:65402/company/api/department'+ "/", JSON.stringify(department))
        .subscribe(res => {
          this.departments = res.json();
        });
```

and this is html:

```
<div [hidden]="!showAddView" align="center">

    <div>
        <label for="editTitle">Department No:</label><br>
        <input #departmentNo placeholder="id">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="editAbrv">Department name:</label><br>
        <input #departmentName placeholder="name">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="editAbrv">Department Location:</label><br>
        <input #departmentLocation placeholder="location">
    </div>

    <div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="addDepartment(department)" title="Add">
            Save
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)=showHide() >
            Cancel
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The full code is here: [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/F6i5ZjHaAVmGvVJsb7e5?p=catalogue)

I don't know how to post this whole model into back-end. It says that department = undefined in my addDepartment method. Thanks for help!

Comment: Hi, It says that department is undefined.

Comment: why not use your wand? ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues with your code:

- You are calling `(click)="addDepartment(department)"` and this `department` doesn't exist anywhere. You can change the div wrapping your inputs to `form` and get the values from it:

  ```
  <form  #f="ngForm" [hidden]="!showAddView" align="center">
    ....
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="addDepartment(f.value)" title="Add">
    ....
  </form>
  ```
- You are not using `Headers` you created. Add them to the `post()` request:

  ```
  this.http.post('~', JSON.stringify(department), { headers: headers })`
  ```
- Also, you probably don't need `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"`, those should be on your server.

Comment: I did as you said but it doesn't work. I think that the problem is in html but I can't see it. Because when I input my values, values are not passed to my method.

Comment: Updated the answer.. Check out the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgForm-directive.html) for more details if you need to. Plunker you linked isn't working, and I can't test the solution at the moment...

Comment: Thanks:) I did it as form and make my inputs:  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="department" ngControl="departmentNo" #departmentNo="ngForm" > , it is now passed as an object. But I've got a error: POST http://localhost:65402/company/api/department/ 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: You are right :D I got in my controller parameters that I send from angular. You are awesome! :)Thank you again!

Comment: I am but I need to earn 15 reputation so that my wote can be visible :)

Comment: When I try to update my model I dont see Two-way binding on my model and it says that Id is undefined. :/ In Angular 1 I make it with no problem, but this is a little confusing to me. Sorry I bother you, but I really want to understand it :)

Comment: Can you put the code in a plunker? Can't read anything here (;

Comment: I would like to, but I need 20 reputation to talk there :( https://plnkr.co/edit/mVFXK8?p=catalogue this is the updated link :)

Comment: this code:     
My controller looks like this: [HttpPut] [Route("Update/{id}")] public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Update(int id, DepartmentModel model)  comes from backend :) id parametar is sent from angular, but id from model is null :/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where your `departement` comes from. I would refactor your code to leverage `ngModel`, as described below:

```
<div [hidden]="!showAddView" align="center">
  <div>
    <label for="editTitle">Department No:</label><br>
    <input [(ngModel)]="departement.departmentNo" placeholder="id">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="editAbrv">Department name:</label><br>
    <input [(ngModel)]="departement.departmentName" placehlder="name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="editAbrv">Department Location:</label><br>
    <input [(ngModel)]="departement.departmentLocation" placeholder="location">
  </div>

  <div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="addDepartment(department)" title="Add">
      Save
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)=showHide() >
      Cancel
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

You should have initialize this property with an empty object:

```
contructor() {
  this.department = {};
}
```

Regarding the headers, there is nothing to send for CORS. The browser will automatically send a `Origin` header containing the domain of the application executing the request. The server will detect it and, if it supports CORS, will send back corresponding headers (including the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` one). This link could give hints about CORS:

- Understanding and using CORS - http://restlet.com/blog/2015/12/15/understanding-and-using-cors/

As underlined by Saxsa, you forgot to use the `headers` into your request...

Comment: I removed the CORS  (it is fixed in backend part). My department is defined like:  department:Department; and Department is a component which has properties: departmentNo, departmentName and departmentLocation.

Comment: My constructor in AppComponent looks like this: constructor(@Inject(Http) private http: Http) {
    this.getAll(this.pageNumber,this.pageSize);
    this.addDepartment(this.department);
  }, and in Department component I added  departmentNo, departmentName and departmentLocation in it.

Comment: `Department` doesn't need to be a component. It will just contain data. It can be a raw JS object or a simple typeScript class.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you try to do in the constructor: get the list of deparments and add a department?